# VisualState.StateTriggers not working

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a two columns `Grid` inside a `SplitView` and a `StateTriggers` is suppose to put the second column to the bottom of the first column and also change the `DisplayMode` of the `SplitView` when the width of Window shrinks. But I can't figure out why it's always two columns and the `DisplayMode` isn't changed either. `xmal` file's posted below.

```
<Page
x:Class="ExampleLayout.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:ExampleLayout"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
Loaded="Page_Loaded"
xmlns:data="using:ExampleLayout.Model"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="#4d4d4d">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="NarrowLayout">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="MySplitView.DisplayMode" Value="Inline" />

                    <Setter Target="FirstItemsGridView.(Grid.Row)" Value="0" />
                    <Setter Target="FirstItemsGridView.(Grid.Column)" Value="0" />
                    <Setter Target="SecondItemsGridView.(Grid.Row)" Value="1" />
                    <Setter Target="SecondItemsGridView.(Grid.Column)" Value="0" />

                    <Setter Target="FirstItemsGridView.(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Value="2" />
                    <Setter Target="SecondItemsGridView.(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Value="2" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="WideLayout">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="400" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="MySplitView.DisplayMode" Value="CompactOverlay" />

                    <Setter Target="FirstItemsGridView.(Grid.Row)" Value="0" />
                    <Setter Target="FirstItemsGridView.(Grid.Column)" Value="0" />
                    <Setter Target="SecondItemsGridView.(Grid.Row)" Value="0" />
                    <Setter Target="SecondItemsGridView.(Grid.Column)" Value="1" />

                    <Setter Target="FirstItemsGridView.(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Value="1" />
                    <Setter Target="SecondItemsGridView.(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Value="1" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <RelativePanel>
        <Button Name="HamburgerButton" 
                RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" 
                Content="&#xE700;"
                FontSize="24"
                Width="45"
                Height="45"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Foreground="White"
                Click="HamburgerButton_Click"
                />

        <TextBlock Name="TitleTextBlock" 
                   RelativePanel.RightOf="HamburgerButton"
                   FontSize="18"
                   FontWeight="Bold"
                   Foreground="White"
                   Margin="20,10,0,0" />
    </RelativePanel>

    <SplitView Name="MySplitView" 
               Grid.Row="1" 
               DisplayMode="Inline" 
               OpenPaneLength="150" 
               CompactPaneLength="45">
        <SplitView.Pane>
            <ListBox SelectionMode="Single" 
                     SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged"
                     Background="#4d4d4d">
                <ListBoxItem Name="Charts">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <TextBlock 
                            Text="&#xe713;"
                            FontFamily="Segoe UI" 
                            Foreground="White"
                            FontWeight="SemiBold"
                            Margin="0,-7,0,0"
                            FontSize="26" />
                        <TextBlock Text="Settings" 
                                   FontSize="20" 
                                   Foreground="White"
                                   Margin="20,0,0,0" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Name="Settings">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock 
                            Text="&#xe713;"
                            FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" 
                            Foreground="White"
                            FontWeight="SemiBold"
                            FontSize="20"
                            Margin="0,3,0,0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Settings" 
                                   FontSize="20" 
                                   Foreground="White"
                                   Margin="20,0,0,0" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListBoxItem>
            </ListBox>
        </SplitView.Pane>
        <SplitView.Content>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <GridView Name="FirstItemsGridView"
                          Grid.Column="0"
                          Background="#333333"
                          ItemsSource="{x:Bind FirstItems}"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                          Margin="5">
                    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:ExampleLayoutItem">
                            <local:FirstSymbolControl />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                </GridView>

                <GridView Name="SecondItemsGridView"
                          Grid.Column="1"
                          Background="#333333"
                          ItemsSource="{x:Bind SecondItems}"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                          Margin="5">
                    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:ExampleLayoutItem">
                            <local:SecondSymbolControl />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                </GridView>

            </Grid>
        </SplitView.Content>
    </SplitView>

</Grid>
```

Comment: On Local Machine, by default, the minimum window width for a UWP app is 500, so 400 may not be a good value for "WideLayout" and this may be the reason why VisualState.StateTriggers not work. You can try set `MinWindowWidth` to `600` like @Michal Kania said and then your code should be able to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that it works. For your "WideLayout" just change

```
<AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="400" />
```

to

```
<AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="600" />
```

Maybe you were checking it on "Local Machine". Then it likes to happen ;)

Comment: Thanks! I were using "Local Machine". changing to `MinWindowWidth="600"` fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue and it turned out, the order of the rules is important, like the framework is matching the rules from top to bottom and uses the first rule that matches. So in your case, minimal width is always greater than 0 som the first rule us always matched. I suggest you try changing the order of your rules, putting the rule with MinWindowWidth="400" before the rule with MinWindowWidth="0"